# Implementing a FIR filter using Vectors

Tags: algorithm, haskell, signal-processing

I have implemented a FIR filter in Haskell. I don't know that much about FIR filters and my code is heavily based on an existing C# implementation. Therefore, I have a feeling that my implementation is has too much of a C# style and is not really Haskell-like. I would like to know if there is a more idiomatic Haskell way of implementing my code. Ideally, I'm lucky for some combination of higher-order functions (map, filter, fold, etc.) that implement the algorithm.

My Haskell code looks like this:

```
  applyFIR :: Vector Double -> Vector Double -> Vector Double
  applyFIR b x = generate (U.length x) help
      where
        help i = if i >= (U.length b - 1) then loop i (U.length b - 1) else 0
        loop yi bi = if bi < 0 then 0 else b !! bi * x !! (yi-bi) + loop yi (bi-1)
        vec !! i = unsafeIndex vec i -- Shorthand for unsafeIndex
```

This code is based on the following C# code:

```
public float[] RunFilter(double[] x)
      {
         int M = coeff.Length;
         int n = x.Length;
         //y[n]=b0x[n]+b1x[n-1]+....bmx[n-M]
         var y = new float[n];
         for (int yi = 0; yi < n; yi++)
         {
            double t = 0.0f;
            for (int bi = M - 1; bi >= 0; bi--)
            {
               if (yi - bi < 0) continue;

               t += coeff[bi] * x[yi - bi];
            }
            y[yi] = (float) t;
         }

         return y;
      }
```

As you can see, it's almost a straight copy. How can I turn my implementation into a more Haskell-like one? Do you have any ideas? The only thing I could come up with was using `Vector.generate`.

I know that the `DSP` library has an implementation available. But it uses lists and is way too slow for my use case. This `Vector` implementation is a lot faster than the one in `DSP`.

I've also tried implementing the algorithm using `Repa`. It is faster than the `Vector` implementation. Here is the result:

```
applyFIR :: V.Vector Float -> Array U DIM1 Float -> Array D DIM1 Float
applyFIR b x = R.traverse x id (\_ (Z :. i) -> if i >= len then loop i (len - 1) else 0)
  where
    len = V.length b
    loop :: Int -> Int -> Float
    loop yi bi = if bi < 0 then 0 else (V.unsafeIndex b bi) * x !! (Z :. (yi-bi)) + loop yi (bi-1)
    arr !! i = unsafeIndex arr i
```

Comment: BTW, this operation is called [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). In the _O_ (_n_ ²) form you have here, this is always slow regardless of language, if both input arrays are big. The industry standard is therefore to use a _fast convolution_ based on [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), which only takes _O_ (_n_ · log _n_). If one of the arrays is small, Daniel Martin's version should be fine, though.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I'll think about looking into using the FFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think that your initial vector code is a faithful translation - that is, I think it disagrees with the C# code. For example, suppose that both "x" and "b" ("b" is `coeff` in C#) have length 3, and have all values of `1.0`. Then for `y[0]` the C# code would produce `x[0] * coeff[0]`, or `1.0`. (it would hit `continue` for all other values of `bi`)

With your Haskell code, however, `help 0` produces 0. Your `Repa` version seems to suffer from the same problem.

So let's start with a more faithful translation:

```
applyFIR :: Vector Double -> Vector Double -> Vector Double
applyFIR b x = generate (U.length x) help
    where
      help i = loop i (min i $ U.length b - 1)
      loop yi bi = if bi < 0 then 0 else b !! bi * x !! (yi-bi) + loop yi (bi-1)
      vec !! i = unsafeIndex vec i -- Shorthand for unsafeIndex
```

Now, you're basically doing a calculation like this for computing, say, `y[3]`:

```
  ... b[3]   |   b[2]   |   b[1]   |   b[0]
      x[0]   |   x[1]   |   x[2]   |   x[3]   |   x[4]   |   x[5]   | ....
           multiply
    b[3]*x[0]|b[2]*x[1] |b[1]*x[2] |b[0]*x[3] 
           sum
      y[3] = b[3]*x[0] + b[2]*x[1] + b[1]*x[2] + b[0]*x[3]
```

So one way to think of what you're doing is "take the `b` vector, reverse it, and to compute spot `i` of the result, line `b[0]` up with `x[i]`, multiply all the corresponding `x` and `b` entries, and compute the sum".

So let's do that:

```
applyFIR :: Vector Double -> Vector Double -> Vector Double
applyFIR b x = generate (U.length x) help
  where
    revB = U.reverse b
    bLen = U.length b
    help i = let sliceLen = min (i+1) bLen
                 bSlice = U.slice (bLen - sliceLen) sliceLen revB
                 xSlice = U.slice (i + 1 - sliceLen) sliceLen x
             in U.sum $ U.zipWith (*) bSlice xSlice
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing an implementation using slices but totally forgot about it for some reason. Thanks a lot for this version (and the correction)! It shaves a good 8 seconds of the time.